# Получение полноценного объекта из массива

Tags: java, массивы, объекты

Массив и получение объекта из него:

```
Spell[] spells=new Spell[4];

public Spell getSpell(int num){
    num--;
    return spells[num];
}
```

У класса **Spell** есть функция `doMagic()` которая переопределяется у дочерних классов, например:

```
public class ArcaneArrow extends Spell{

    public ArcaneArrow(){
        setName("Стрела из магии");
    }

    @Override
    public void doMagic(Main main, Player player, Enemy enemy)
    {   
        ParticleSystem ps = new ParticleSystem(main, 20, main.getImageSource("pics/particles/magic.png"), 400);
        ps.setScaleRange(0.1f, 1f);
        ps.setSpeedByComponentsRange(-0.02f, 0.02f, -0.5f, 0f);
        ps.setAcceleration(0.0001f, 90);
        ps.setRotationSpeedRange(0, 360);
        ps.setFadeOut(300, new AccelerateInterpolator());
        ps.oneShot(main.enemyLayer, 20);
        setParticles(ps);
        main.addBattleLog("Вы использовали заклинание "+name);
        enemy.hurt(player);
    }
}
```

Но при получении любого объекта из массива я получаю не то что нужно, а экземпляр родительского класса и функцией

```
public void doMagic(Main main, Player player, Enemy enemy){
    player.changeHealth(10);
}
```

Которая и выполняется вместо нужной.

Итак, вопрос: 
Есть ли способ получить из массива элемент **ArcaneArrow** для дальнейшего вызова переопределенной функции `doMagic()`?

Comment: Как вы заполняете этот массив `spells`?

Comment: public void addSpell(int id){
   spells[0]=new ArcaneArrow();
 } К примеру.

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то после выбрасывания всего не относящегося к вопросу кода остаётся [такой пример](https://goo.gl/Sx2H5B). И работает он корректно. И это нормально, учитывая виртуальность методов в Java.

Comment: Таким образом работает корректно, да, но мне нужно чтобы он работал корректно и после вноса в массив и выноса. И вот тут на ум приходит только: сделать весь код в суперклассе и вызывать его кусок через "id", устанавливаемый дочерним классом.

Comment: Да он любым образом будет работать корректно. Хоть прямо в инициализации массива добавите объекты, хоть потом где-то позже. Добавьте в  вопрос [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) кода, а иначе в этом всём нет никакого смысла. И обратите также, пожалуйста, внимание на слова **минимальный** (то есть не нужно толкать параметры и большое тело в метод `doMagic`, если проблема воспроизводится и без них) и **самодостаточный** - не должно быть такого, что приходится самому придумывать как у вас выглядит класс `Spell`.

Comment: Было бы корректно, то я бы не писал этот вопрос, то что нужно знать про класс `Spell` указал (то, что дочерний переопределяет функцию `doMagic`)

Comment: Проблема в том как вы описали свой вопрос. Ни по тексту, ни по коду непонятно как воспроизвести вашу проблему. Нет понимания - нет и решения. Я не поленился собрать минимальный и самодостаточный пример за вас 45 минут назад, но в нём все прекрасно работает.

Comment: Проблема при вытаскивании объекта из массива, т.к. я получаю тип `Spell`, был вопрос как мне вытащить объект в исходном формате.

Comment: Вот [пример с методом](https://goo.gl/pnUMEK) `getSpell`. Всё работает корректно. Приведите пример на http://www.tutorialspoint.com когда код работает некорректно - тогда и поговорим.

Comment: На том сайте всё работает корректно, но на андроиде при выполнении этого кода я получаю ответ от родительской функции...

Comment: @Regent , спасибо. Проблема решилась как только я добавил модификатор `static`, до этого в любом случае код возвращал тип `Spell`.

Comment: Хорошо, конечно, что у вас всё заработало, но вообще [тот же пример](https://goo.gl/oCmQt9) без `static` вполне себе работает. Может, у вас что-то где-то неудачно закешировалось и только после изменения кода (добавления `static`) пересобралось правильно. Маловероятно, но мало ли.